# Android: changing density for game performance?

Tags: android

I currently have a note 4 which has a high resolution screen (2560x1440) that, when playing in the native resolution, doesn't perform well somtimes.

I have found apps on the play store that will allow resolution changes but all require root (at&t version is currently unrootable).

I can however change the density of the screen without root.

I'm curious if I would receive the same performance boost changing density as I would changing resolution?

Answer (score 0):

Highly unlikely.

The resolution defines number of pixels displayed on the screen. When you change the resolution, the system changes the size of all image buffers used for rendering. It means that there is different numer of pixels to shade and draw.

On the other hand there's the density, which define, how much pixels you can fit on one inch of the physical screen. The density changes an internal matrix used for scaling images. The operation is always same. In apps with native Android UI you may gain a small boost, because by changing the density value you can change the density type of your screen (medium, high, xhigh, etc.). This will change the drawable folder used by the app to the (potentially) smaller one, which will result in faster image loading and messed up UI.

This trick won't work for the games, because in most cases games don't care about the drawable folders.